# Disable SwiftLint for XCode autogenerated Siri Intents swift files

Tags: swiftlint

How to disable SwiftLint for XCode autogenerated *.swift files?
For example for Siri Intents?

[image: Errors and Warnings in XCode]

Comment: I've added 'build' folder into excluded section and it's solved the problem. 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify folders and files in the `excluded` section of the `.swiftlint.yml` file as discussed in the [documentation](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/).

E.g., you might have an `excluded` section like so:

```yaml
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
  - Carthage
  - Pods
  - Source/ExcludedFolder
  - Source/ExcludedFile.swift
  - Source/*/ExcludedFile.swift # Exclude files with a wildcard
```

Comment: It's autogenerated files. Xcode automatically create them in the 'build' folder of my project.
I've added 'build' folder into excluded section and it solve the problem.